# Cell numeric value

Tags: excel, sum

I created an assessment form on Excel and willing to upgrade with below intended feature. Table looks like:

```
+--------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|                    | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
+--------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| Computer knowledge |   |   |   |   |   |
+--------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| Office Knowledge   |   |   |   |   |   |
+--------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| Relationships      |   |   |   |   |   |
+--------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

When I put `x` or any character on this table I want Excel to assign column value and summary the score like below:

```
+-------------+----+
| Total Score | 17 |
+-------------+----+
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I assume the following table would yield a total score of 10:

[image]

Technically you could put any character you want in the cells, but counting non-empty cells in the columns and multiplying each by the factor should accomplish what you want.

Cell B6 is the following:

```
=(COUNTA(B2:B4)*1)+(COUNTA(C2:C4)*2)+(COUNTA(D2:D4)*3)+(COUNTA(E2:E4)*4)+(COUNTA(F2:F4)*5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) that references the block of cells which might contain an *X* and use that to sum either the value in the corresponding row 1 or zero.

[image: SUM over INDEX]

The standard formula in B6 is,

```
=SUM(INDEX((B2:F4="X")*(B1:F1), , ))
```

This could be modified to look for *any* value, not just an *X* like this.

```
=SUM(INDEX((B2:F4<>"")*(B1:F1), , ))
```